# How to handle paths for transpiled JS?

Tags: typescript, transpiler

So I have a monorepo workspace with a common folder that's shared with my express app. My common folder transpiles to JS inside common/dist, and i would like my transpiled express code to be able to access that. So how do I handle imports when my ts files use common/schema but the js files will need common/dist/schema?

Answer (score -2):

To handle imports when your TypeScript files use `common/schema` but the JavaScript files will need `common/dist/schema`, you can use TypeScript path mapping and configure your module resolution appropriately.

Here's how you can set it up:

1. **Configure TypeScript Path Mapping**: In your TypeScript configuration file (`tsconfig.json`), you can define path mappings to alias `common/schema` to `common/dist/schema`. This allows TypeScript to resolve imports from `common/schema` to the correct transpiled JavaScript files.

   ```json
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "baseUrl": ".",
       "paths": {
         "common/schema": ["common/dist/schema"]
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. **Use Relative Imports in TypeScript Files**: Inside your TypeScript files, import modules using relative paths (`import ... from './schema'`). TypeScript will resolve these imports based on the path mapping configuration.
3. **Compile TypeScript Code**: When you compile your TypeScript code, ensure that it generates JavaScript files in the correct directory (`common/dist`).
4. **Require Transpiled Modules in JavaScript Files**: In your JavaScript files, you can require transpiled modules using the appropriate relative path (`require('./schema')`).

With this setup, TypeScript will resolve imports from `common/schema` to the correct transpiled JavaScript files located in `common/dist/schema`, allowing your TypeScript and JavaScript files to work seamlessly together within your Express application.